# How can i fix this Esc Key error?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, richtextbox, runtime-error

I have this chunk of code in my Notepad clone program, it is to track my carat location in my `RichTextBox` and has been working fine for me.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Curpos();
    }

    private static int EM_LINEINDEX = 0xbb;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wparam, int lparam);

    private void Curpos()
    {
        {
            int line, col, index;
            index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
            col = index - SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, -1, 0);
            Lblcurpos.Text = "Line: " + (++line).ToString() + ", Column:"  + (++col).ToString();
        }
    }
```

It has been working perfectly for me, until i added some code so that i could close my program with the Esc Key.
Here is the code for my Esc Key:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This is where it has the problem:

`index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;`

When i am doing this, i can run my program fine, type text in my `RichTextBox` and everything but when i press the Esc Key it says:

> Cannot Access disposed object
>   Object name: 'RichTextBox'

Then is says:

> **Trouble Shooting Tips:**
>   Make sure you have not released a resource before attempting to use this.
>   Get general help for this exception

Any ideas on what i can do? I tried to use the shortcut keys but it doesn't have a Esc key you can use for the shortcut. Any help with either doing a different shortcut or a fix to this problem, i would like it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Application.Exit();
```

instead of

```
this.Close();
```

**From MSDN:**

[**Application.Exit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed. This is the code to use if you are have called Application.Run (WinForms applications), this method stops all running message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the application.

Comment: Sorry about not posting where my error is shown, see my last edit.

Comment: I did something wrong when i tried it first and it didn't work, just tried it again and it worked...Don't know what i did wrong.

Comment: Using Application.Exit() is not exactly equivalent to closing a window.  This answer doesn't address the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that Application.Exit() is **not** a substitute for this.Close().  Exit() terminates the entire application, Close() just close the form.

There are better ways to avoid accidents like this.  When you handle shortcut keystrokes like you did, you should always set e.Handled and e.SuppressKeyPress to true so the keystroke will be completely dismissed and not generate any additional events.  Like the one that bombed your code.

By far the best way is to use the dedicated method for this in Winforms, ProcessCmdKey().  It implements true shortcut keystroke behavior, the KeyPreview property is a VB6 compatibility feature which is close but not equivalent.  Make it look like this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
            this.Close();
            return true;   // Used, don't process any further
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```